# Getting a list of all components rendered on server side using react-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently looking for a way of getting a list of all components that have been server-side rendered on react-dom.

The reason for this is because I want to inject a pre-defined list of translation key for each of the component, then combine this list and export in HTML to reduce a need for loading the full translation file.

My idea is to define a definition for a component like this:

```
MyComponent.translations = [
 'key1',
 'key2''
];
```

And by getting a list of components that have been rendered, I can combine this list of keys and do a translation of those keys before sending to the client.

I am also open to another way of solving this issue. (maybe context?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do some trick, if you are using some kind of translation lib such as `react-i18next`, you can wrap the *translation* function (only when SSR) with something that will save aside all the keys that this function was called with...